# How to get all combinations of available keys in a string

Tags: ruby, string, substitution

I have a string like this:

```
'show -drum-, -drum- and -drum-'
```

And an array of options for each `/-[a-z]+-/` key:

```
{
  '-drum-' => %w{kick snare hihat crash},
  ...
}
```

I'd like to make all the possible substitutions including:

```
[
  'show kick, snare and hihat',
  'show kick, hihat and snare',
  'show snare, hihat and kick',
  'show snare, kick and hihat',
  'show hihat, snare and kick',
  'show hihat, kick and snare',
  'show crash, kick and snare',
  'show crash, snare and kick',
  'show hihat, snare and crash',
  ...
]
```

Ideally, this would happen without any repetition, although I would accept a solution which would return, for instance 'show kick, kick and kick', etc.

There are other key substitutions in the hash, so I'd have to do unique combinations of those, too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "...I would accept a solution..." - we expect to see your effort in solving the problem. What have you tried? Why didn't it work? It's not good to assume we'll write a solution if you haven't tried, so please show us your work for us to correct rather than write something from scratch. Read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun challenge.

```
def each_replacement(pattern, repl_keys)
  return enum_for(__method__, pattern, repl_keys) unless block_given?

  pattern.gsub!('%', '%%')
  keys = repl_keys.keys
  key_counts = Hash[keys.map { |key| [key, pattern.scan(key).count] }]
  key_permutations = repl_keys.lazy.map { |key, repl|
    combinations = repl.combination(key_counts[key])
    combinations.flat_map { |comb|
      comb.permutation.to_a
    }
  }.inject(&:product)
  key_permutations.each do |perm|
    text = pattern
    keys.zip(perm).each do |key, repl|
      text = text.gsub(key, '%s') % repl
    end
    yield text
  end
end

pattern = '-action- -drum-, -drum- and -drum-'
keys = {
  '-drum-' => %w{kick snare hihat crash},
  '-action-' => %w{hit smash}
}
puts each_replacement(pattern, keys).to_a
```

Comment: That's great, thanks! Exactly what I needed. There's a few new methods for me to learn about here :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['kick','snare', 'hihat']
a.permutation.each do |p|
  puts "play %s, %s and %s" % p
end
```

There is a built-in `permutation` function. In the example above, store everything in an array and just call `permutation`. After that use `p` and interpolate the values in the target string.

The output is:

```
play kick, snare and hihat
play kick, hihat and snare
play snare, kick and hihat
play snare, hihat and kick
play hihat, kick and snare
play hihat, snare and kick
```

Here is the generalized form:

```
rep = {
  '-drum-' => %w{kick snare hihat crash},
  '-zoo-' => %w{zebra lion dog},
  '-one-' => %w{one},
  '-ping-' => %w{pong noreply}
}

template = 'show -drum- on -zoo-, -one- -ping- for -drum-, -ping- for -drum- or -drum- -zoo- -zoo-'
accumulator = []
accumulator << template

rep.keys.each do |key|
  new_accumulator = []
  accumulator.each do |acc|
    transformed_template = acc.gsub(key, '%s')
    rep[key].permutation.each do |p|
     new_accumulator << transformed_template % p
    end
  end
  accumulator = new_accumulator
end

accumulator.each do |fin|
  puts fin
end
```

Comment: I'm perhaps not being clear, there won't always be three keys and three places to put them. There's actually seven items in the drum array.

Comment: It works the same with seven keys and seven places to put them.

Comment: How about seven keys and three places? Or seven and one?

Comment: yep. you can do more than 1. You're just extrapolating this solution

Comment: Thanks! This may actually be a slightly tidier solution than @Amadan suggested. I'll have to do some benchmarking to decide.

Comment: think is't a bit more straightforward. if you need to optimize performance, you can take it even further by generating all of the permutations beforehand and interpolating (this will pay the penalty of multiple string interpolations for each result).

Comment: From a brief look on my smartphone, I think it overgenerates if there's at least two more replacements than slots for a key.

Comment: of course. validation to ensure number of slots == number of replacements should be put in place to catch issues like this

Comment: It's not about validation - OP's comment from this very answer: "How about seven keys and three places? Or seven and one?" There was a reason I used `combination`.

Comment: oh. did not catch that. the use of combination is pretty straightforward though.

Answer (score 0):

With single target-replacement pair:

```
target = /-drum-/
replacement = %w{kick snare hihat}
a = ["show -drum-, -drum- and -drum-"]
while a.first =~ target
  a = a.flat_map{|s| replacement.map{|r| s.sub(target, r)}}
end
a # => ["show kick, kick and kick", "show kick, kick and snare", "show kick, kick and hihat", "show kick, snare and kick", "show kick, snare and snare", "show kick, snare and hihat", "show kick, hihat and kick", "show kick, hihat and snare", "show kick, hihat and hihat", "show snare, kick and kick", "show snare, kick and snare", "show snare, kick and hihat", "show snare, snare and kick", "show snare, snare and snare", "show snare, snare and hihat", "show snare, hihat and kick", "show snare, hihat and snare", "show snare, hihat and hihat", "show hihat, kick and kick", "show hihat, kick and snare", "show hihat, kick and hihat", "show hihat, snare and kick", "show hihat, snare and snare", "show hihat, snare and hihat", "show hihat, hihat and kick", "show hihat, hihat and snare", "show hihat, hihat and hihat"]
a.length # => 27
```